# Kafka 0.8 All Good & rocks! .... Kafka 0.7 not able to make it happen

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

Kafka 0.8 works great. I am able to use CLI as well as write my own producers/consumers!

Checking Zookeeper... and I see all the topics and partitions created successfully for 0.8.

Kafka 0.7 does not work!

Why Kafka 0.7? I am using Kafka Spout from Storm which is made for Kafka 0.7.

First I just want to run CLI based producer/consumer for Kafka 0.7, which I am unable to. I carry out the following steps:

1. I delete all the topics/partitions etc. in Zookeeper that were created from my Kafka 0.8
2. I change the dataDir in zoo.cfg to point to different location.
3. Now I start the kafka server 0.7. It starts successfully. However I don’t know why it again registers the broker topics I deleted?
4. Now I start the Kafka Producer :

   bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topicime
       & it starts successfully:
       [2013-06-28 14:06:05,521] INFO zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
       [2013-06-28 14:06:05,606] INFO Creating async producer for broker id = 0 at 0:0 (kafka.producer.ProducerPool)
5. Time to send some messages & oops I get this error:

   [2013-06-28 14:07:19,650] INFO Disconnecting from 0:0 (kafka.producer.SyncProducer)
   [2013-06-28 14:07:19,653] ERROR Connection attempt to 0:0 failed, next attempt in 1 ms (kafka.producer.SyncProducer)
   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
           at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
           at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:364)
           at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:356)
           at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:623)
           at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.connect(SyncProducer.scala:173)
           at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.getOrMakeConnection(SyncProducer.scala:196)
           at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:92)
           at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.multiSend(SyncProducer.scala:135)
           at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.send(DefaultEventHandler.scala:58)
           at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:44)
           at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:116)
           at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:254)
           at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:70)
           at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:41)

Note that Zookeeper is already running.

Any help would really be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I don't even see the topic being created in zookeeper. I am running the following command:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topicime
```

After the command everything is fine & I get the following message:

```
[2013-06-28 14:30:17,614] INFO Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13f805c6673004b, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2013-06-28 14:30:17,615] INFO zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2013-06-28 14:30:17,700] INFO Creating async producer for broker id = 0 at 0:0 (kafka.producer.ProducerPool)
```

However now when i type a string to send I get the above error (Connection refused!)

Comment: They have done a lot of fixes and changes in the 0.8 version. Also the Consumer API is modified and enriched significantly. I believe  u should moved to 0.8 rather than tackling 0.7 issues unless you have a very definite reason to stick to it

Comment: @Hild: It was because of Kafka Spout (Storm) that I am using which is written for Kafka 0.7.

Comment: You might want to have look [here](https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-kafka-0.8-plus), it uses the Kafka 0.8 release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INFO Disconnecting from 0:0 (kafka.producer.SyncProducer)
```

The above line has the error hidden in it. 0:0 is not a valid host and port. The solution is to explicitly set the host ip to be registered in Zookeeper by setting the "hostname" property in server.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking out the storm-kafka fork, available at https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-kafka-0.8-plus

I'm installing it right now for our servers =).